# Java Android: How to use Predicate<T> and Room together to retrieve specific elements from a database?

Tags: java, android, android-room, predicate

I'm coming from a C# background and trying to implement an Android App. In .Net C#, retrieving specific data from a database is relatively easy using [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) and Linq, my usual approach is something like this (simplified for clarity):

```
public IQueryable<T> GetElements<T>()
        where T : class, IDBKeyProvider
{
    return this.db.Set<T>().Where(e => e.Dbstate == (int)DBState.Active);
}
```

This method call results in a generic `IQueryable` and later on, I can use the power of [deferred execution and expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution) to specify *exactly* which elements I want using a [predicate](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-predicate), loading only desired elements in memory.

This is something I would very much like to go for in my Android App, however, I'm not exactly sure how I could arrive at a similar result, if I can at all. 
I looked into some [Java Predicate](https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/how-to-use-predicate-in-java-8/) examples, which seemed promising and I also found [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) to be delightfully familiar. My problem, however, is that I cannot make my queries fully customizable due to the fact that, Room still needs some hard-coded info about my db (original [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data)):

```
@Dao
public interface MyDao {
     @Query("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM user WHERE region IN (:regions)")
     public LiveData<List<User>> loadUsersFromRegionsSync(List<String> regions);
}
```

I could perhaps extract the relevant pieces of information with [Java Reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html) from the predicate parameter, but I feel this to be a hack rather than a proper solution.